Why paper folds happen only along straight lines?
This is a question from Tristan Needham's Differential Geometry textbook:

Why paper folds into a straight line? We take it for granted that when
we fold a piece of paper, the fold automatically forms itself into a
straight line, but why does this happen? Show
that this is a direct consequence of the Theorema
Egregium.

I know that the principal curvatures in a paper is $\kappa_1 = \kappa_2 = 0$. And that the Theorema Egregium promises that the Gaussian curvature $K = \kappa_1 \cdot \kappa_2$ at every point $p$ on the paper remains invariant under isometries, such as folding.
I'm not sure how to proceed.
I've tried assuming by contradiction that we've folded along a non-straight line. Then  at the new curved "boundary" there is a non-zero principal curvature. But this feels non-exact, since I'm not sure how to even define principal curvatures along the boundary.

Since paper is not elastic within the surface, the Gaussian curvature $K=\kappa_1\cdot\kappa_2$ is always $0$. That is why you may bend a sheet of paper to form a pipe but not a sphere. Folding is like bending a half-pipe with radius close to $0$, thus the fold is locally the intersection of two (flat) planes what results in a straight line (with regard to the two plains, but since the radius of the fold is almost $0$ it may be bend perpendicular to the plains).
